# Format URL using PHP - http://www.google.com to www.google.com/; Also having trouble with str_replace()

Tags: php, url, str-replace, substr

I am having some trouble performing the following operation..

> http://www.google.com --> www.google.com/
>   https://google.com --> www.google.com/
>   google.com --> www.google.com/

I am trying to remove `https:// or http://`, ensure that `www.` is added to the beginning of the URL, and then add a trailing slash to the URL if it does not exist.

Feeling like I've gotten the majority of this figured out but I can't get `str_replace()` to work how I'd like it to.

To my understanding this is how to use `str_replace`:

```
$string = 'Hello friends';
str_replace('friends', 'enemies', $string);
echo $string;
// outputs 'Hello enemies' on the page
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com';

echo reformat_url($url);

function reformat_url($url) {
    if ( substr( $url, 0, 7 ) == 'http://' || substr( $url, 0, 8 ) == 'https://' ) { // if http:// or https:// is at the beginning of the url
        $remove = array('http://', 'https://');
        foreach ( $remove as $r ) {
            if ( strpos( $url, $r ) == 0 ) {
                str_replace($r, '', $url); // remove the http:// or https:// -- can't get this to work
            }
        }
    }
    if ( substr( $url, 0, 4 ) != 'www.') { // if www. is not at the beginning of the url
        $url = 'www.' . $url; // prepend www. to the beginning
    }
    if ( substr( $url, -1 ) !== '/' ) { // if trailing slash does not exist
        $url = $url . '/';  // add trailing slash
    }
    return $url; // return the formatted url
}
```

Any assistance on a way to format the URL would be greatly appreciated; also I'm more curious regarding what I am doing wrong with str_replace to remove http:// or https://. If anyone could offer some insight as to what I am doing incorrectly it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, this is not how you should use `str_replace`.

Comment: Thanks Alvin, I was misunderstanding how to use it. I now understand that it does not modify the subject argument you provide to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do

```
$url = str_replace($r, '', $url);
```

instead of

```
str_replace($r, '', $url);
```

because [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) returns a new string; it doesn't change `$url`.

Answer (score 5):

Try [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url).

> #### Return Values
>
> On seriously malformed URLs, `parse_url()` may return FALSE.
>
> If the component parameter is omitted, an associative array is returned. At least one element will be present within the array. Potential keys within this array are:
>
> - `scheme` - e.g. `http`
> - `host`
> - `port`
> - `user`
> - `pass`
> - `path`
> - `query` - after the question mark `?`
> - `fragment` - after the hashmark `#`

So you can access the domain with this code:

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/search...";
$details = parse_url($url);
echo($details['host']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = str_replace('http://', '', $url);
$url = str_replace('https://', '', $url);
if(substr( $url, 0, 4 ) != 'www.')
{
    $url = 'www.'.$url;
}
$length = strlen($url);
if($url[$length-1] != '/')
$url = $url.'/';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function formatURLs($t) {
    $t = ' '.$t;
    $t = preg_replace("#([\s]+)([a-z]+?)://([a-z0-9\-\.,\?!%\*_\#:;~\\&$@\/=\+]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"\\2://\\3\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">\\3</a>", $t);
    $t = preg_replace("#([\s]+)www\.([a-z0-9\-]+)\.([a-z0-9\-.\~]+)((?:/[a-z0-9\-\.,\?!%\*_\#:;~\\&$@\/=\+]*)?)#i", "\\1<a href=\"http://www.\\2.\\3\\4\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">\\2.\\3\\4</a>", $t);
    $t = preg_replace("#([\s]+)([a-z0-9\-_.]+)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)?[\w]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $t);
    $t = substr($t, 1);
    return $t;
}
```

my function, hope will help